The two week notice
I was wondering, do you have to give a two week notice to take a vacation? I want to take a vacation but they told me that I have to give a written notice before the 15th

In what country or state is this in? What does the employee manual say?

Is your job one that requires others to be scheduled to work to cover your responsibilities?  Lead time matters

In The Netherlands, employers are legally required to accept/allow your request if you put it in more than two weeks in advance, but they do have two weeks from the moment you put in the request to object/deny if it is in the critical interest of the business (e.g. too many people on vacation, or very busy period), but they have to give you the time off some other time (that is, they can't always object). If you put in your request less than two weeks in advance, you're basically at their mercy, but I've never had an employer where that has been a real problem.

This highly depends on the company general policy. It also depends on whether or not they have too many tasks and not enough employees to handle the tasks.
Generally, if a company is too busy with many projects and customers, they can deny the requests for vacation from employees (especially if the requests are not made too far in advance.)
